# Session in Struts 2

Tags: java, session, struts2

Is this the correct way of storing a value in session in Struts2?

```
Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("user", "USERNAME");
```

Comment: you can do that, but the preferred way of way is by implementing SessionAware interface. Read [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/how-do-we-get-access-to-the-session.html) and [here](http://splinter.com.au/how-to-use-sessions-with-struts-2) for more information.

Comment: Getting session object from actionContext is not a problem because it's implemented on TheadLocal though it's not a good practice.

Comment: `SessionAware` is definitely preferred; makes action testing much easier.

Comment: I am with Dave here, though there is no issue at all with this but i believe using `SessionAware` is much more diligent and more flexible way

Answer (score 1):

SessionAware interface in struts 2.x, our Action class needs to implement SessionAware interface in order to get HTTP Session behavior into our Action class.

If we implement from SessionAware interface we need to override the method setSession() by SessionAware in our action class.  If we implement our action class from SessionAware interface then struts 2 controller doesn’t inject exactly session object, but it will injects a Map object with similar behavior.

```
 Map m;
 public void setSession(Map m)
    {
        this.m=m;
    }

 public String execute()
    {
        m.put("user", "USERNAME");


        return SUCCESS;
    }
```